# Unable to connect to mysql while installing phabricator

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, phabricator

I am installing phabricator in linux and followed the installation guide from https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/installation_guide/ and also from http://www.tecmint.com/install-phabricator-in-linux/

When i try to access phabricator from web url, i am getting response like

```
    Unable to connect to MySQL!

     Attempt to connect to root@127.0.0.1 failed with error #2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13).

     Make sure Phabricator and MySQL are correctly configured.

To update these 4 value(s), run these command(s) from the command line:
phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.host value
phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.port value
phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.user value
phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set mysql.pass value
```

When i configured my mysql and if i run `phabricator/ $ ./bin/storage upgrade` i am getting error as

```
   [2015-01-20 18:12:04] EXCEPTION: (AphrontAccessDeniedQueryException) #1044: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'phabricator_audit' at [<phutil>/src/aphront/storage/connection/mysql/AphrontBaseMySQLDatabaseConnection.php:301]
  #0 AphrontBaseMySQLDatabaseConnection::throwQueryCodeException(integer, string) called at [<phutil>/src/aphront/storage/connection/mysql/AphrontBaseMySQLDatabaseConnection.php:275]
  #1 AphrontBaseMySQLDatabaseConnection::throwQueryException(mysqli) called at [<phutil>/src/aphront/storage/connection/mysql/AphrontBaseMySQLDatabaseConnection.php:181]
  #2 AphrontBaseMySQLDatabaseConnection::executeRawQuery(string) called at [<phutil>/src/xsprintf/queryfx.php:6]
  #3 queryfx(AphrontMySQLiDatabaseConnection, string, string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/management/PhabricatorStorageManagementAPI.php:219]
  #4 PhabricatorStorageManagementAPI::applyPatchSQL(string) called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/storage/management/workflow/PhabricatorStorageManagementUpgradeWorkflow.php:109]
  #5 PhabricatorStorageManagementUpgradeWorkflow::execute(PhutilArgumentParser) called at [<phutil>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:396]
  #6 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflowsFull(array) called at [<phutil>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:292]
  #7 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflows(array) called at [<phabricator>/scripts/sql/manage_storage.php:171]
```

If i run `./bin/storage upgrade --user root --password root` i am getting error as

```
Raw MySQL Error: Attempt to connect to root@localhost failed with error
#1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

This is my apache settings,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin root@xxx.yyy.com
        ServerName xxx.yyy.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myprojectapp/phabricator/webroot
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
<Directory "/var/www/html/myprojectapp/phabricator/webroot">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have followed all the instruction provided in the installation guide. Can anyone help me to point out my mistake?

Comment: Did your try setting `mysql.host`, `mysql.pass`, `mysql.port`, 
and `mysql.user` with `bin/config set`?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yes i did :( when i run storage upgrade, am getting the error

Comment: And did you try using `127.0.0.1` for the host as opposed to `localhost` Also can you connect with the command line mysql client using the same credentials (ie. `mysql -u username -p -h hostname`)?

Comment: i tried as you suggested and getting the below error,
    [root@codereview phabricator]# ./bin/storage upgrade
MySQL Credentials Not Configured
Unable to connect to MySQL using the configured credentials. You must configure standard credentials before you can upgrade storage. Run these
commands to set up credentials:
 
Raw MySQL Error: Attempt to connect to root@127.0.0.1 failed with error
#1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
[root@codereview phabricator]#

Comment: even after setting host, port, user and pass, i am getting error like MySQL Credentials Not Configured.

Comment: I solved this issue by upgrading mysql version to mysql5.5 from mysql5.1 and also installed the phabricator in another linux box. I am not sure whether upgrading mysql5.5 solved this issue.

Comment: Setting the mysql.host to `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost` like @prodigitalson suggested fixed the issue in my case. Thanks!

Comment: I ran the ./bin commands with "sudo" and it worked for me

Comment: @prodigitalson suggestion worked in my case. Thanks. I have deployed phabricator on lightsail instance with ubuntu 18, for anyone having this scenario :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Phabricator creates *a lot* of `phabricator_` databases so this should do the trick:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `phabricator\_%`.* TO phabricatoruser@'localhost';
```

You can try to limit the privileges as well.

Comment: No need to grant the Phabricator user all privileges on _all_ databases. Phabricator creates tables within the `phabricator_` namespace. Therefore, it's more secure to limit the Phabricator account privileges to that namespace. Use the following commands instead: ```grant all privileges on `phabricator\_%`.* to phabricatoruser@'localhost';```

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem the fixing was so easy :

```
./bin/config set mysql.host 'localhost'

./bin/config set mysql.user 'root'

./bin/config set mysql.pass 'pass'
```

don't forget the "quotes" i spent 2 days for fix this issue !!

Comment: It is not a good idea to give root permissions to a web application.

Answer (score 1):

it was a selinux problem.
disabling it solves it.
1 edit this file vim /etc/selinux/config
2 change SELINUX=enforcing ---> SELINUX=disabled
3 reboot

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your database user do not have create privileges.

login using mysql: `mysql -u user -p`
and try: `create database temp;`

If the database is not created then you need to grant create privileges to your user.

Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) for the mysql Grant syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just got the same issue, I fixed it after few hours :(

Seems that my password has dolar sign **$** at the end.

I changed the mysql password to a simple letters and numbers, without special characters.

Strange, but this fixed the problem for me!

I did not made any additional investigations but seems to be a problem with special characters inside the mysql passwords.

Comment: The '$' sign is a command in bash, therefore can't be used. If you really need to, you can edit the 'local.json' file from phab and insert it manually.